# ORDER BY specified order

Tags: php, mysql

Simplified:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY category") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $cat = $row['category'];
    echo $cat."<br />";
}
```

`mytable` holds Apple, Banana, Citrus

I want the result to display in a specific order, like Banana, Apple, Citrus.

How do I make my query?

Comment: First, stop using mysql_ anything. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php The big red box will explain why.

Comment: You already have the ORDER BY in your query. The only other thing you can add is ASC or DESC. When using that on a text field it will be alphabetical numbers are self explanatory. Ascending is lowest to highest (A-Z) and Descending is (z-a).

Comment: B,A,C does it make sense? It doesnt so how the system should know how do you want to order it? You can use ORDER BY category DESC or ORDER BY category ASC, or then create some specify order by yourself but it wont be easy and I think you're not asking for it, and do not use _fetch_array, use instead _fetch_assoc.

Comment: @Wiggler I agree that fetch_assoc() makes it clearer, but you do know that fetch_array() does the same thing? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: @Rottingham sure, that i know :) But it is same like using print instead of echo, where you can use echo, use it. Just to reduce bad habits :]

Comment: You can get data in DESC OR ASC order . Or you can sort data by value . As I see you require data not match with both ASC and DESC so there is only one way remaining . Its by value . Will you please provide value then I can suggest you

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by field(...)`:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY FIELD(category, 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Citrus');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field - manual for FIELD() function.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from a response at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

"If you want to explicity specify the order of which 'order by' comes back in, like if you had a priority field that had the values "Low" "High" or "Medium" .. do this:

```
select * from tablename order by priority='High' DESC, priority='Medium' DESC, priority='Low" DESC;"
```

For your case, this would be:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY category='Banana' DESC, category='Apple' DESC, category='Citrus' DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
$cat = $row['category'];
echo $cat."<br />";
}
```